# Using sstream parser integer in a char array

Tags: c++

I have trapped for hours when using sstream to parser integer in a char array.
I don't know why there is one more iteration in while loop.

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
int main()
{
    char data[5] = "1 23";
    //char data[4] = {'1', ' ', '2', '3'};  another attempt
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << data;
    int count = 1;
    while (stream)
    {
        double x = 0;
        stream >> x;
        std::cout << count << "  " << x << std::endl;
        count++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the program output shows that:

```
1  1
2  23
3  0
```

I use the follow command to compile the program.

```
g++ main.cpp
```

I think that there are 2 integer,so there are only 2 iteration. I don't know why there are 3 iteration in while loop. I suppose it is because the '\0' at the end of char array, but I tried, it get the same result.

Any Suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think that there are 2 integer,so there are only 2 iteration. I don't know why there are 3 iteration in while loop.

- First iteration: The stream is in a good state. You extract an integer. You print the integer without checking whether the extraction succeeded (it did).
- Second iteration: The stream is in a good state. You extract an integer. You print the integer without checking whether the extraction succeeded (it did).
- Third iteration: The stream is in a good state. You extract an integer. You print the integer without checking whether the extraction succeeded (it had not).
- Fourth iteration: The stream is in a failed state. The loop ends.

The conventional pattern for stream extraction is:

```
while(stream >> variable) { // or if for single extraction
                            // use the extracted variable
```

This way you always check the success of the extraction before using the extracted value.

---

> ```
> char data[4] = {'1', ' ', '2', '3'};  another attempt
> ```

This attempt has undefined behaviour as soon as you insert the non-null terminated string into the stream.

Comment: but why in third iteration, the stream is in a good state? there seems no thing in the stream.

Comment: @XuHui Stream is in a good state because the previous extraction was successful.

Answer (score 2):

You are not checking `stream >> x` for success:

```
if (stream >> x)
{
    std::cout << count << "  " << x << std::endl;
    count++;
}
```

will do the job.

You can also include it in the loop:

```
double x = 0;
while (stream >> x)
{
    std::cout << count << "  " << x << std::endl;
    count++;
}
```